# Why rendering a group of svgs differs from one svg?

Tags: svg

I have 3 SVGs in a web page. when I use each one of them individually, its rendering is ok and as expected. but together in one page they render not correctly. as you can see in this picture only number2 is rendering correctly (the white circles on it)
[image: as you can see in this picture only number2 is rendering correctly]

I get the svg from designer and I just want to know if this problem is related to the svg code or not.

and here is the svg codes:

number2:

```
<svg id="number2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="115.436" height="151.083" viewBox="0 0 115.436 151.083">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <path id="Path_11866" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 11866" d="M660.176,340.232q-3.36-1.878-3.112-16.8T658.1,305.25q5.579-23.213,20.556-34.835A144.034,144.034,0,0,1,714.133,250.7q8.3-3.272,7.66-6.819T717,238.595a14.694,14.694,0,0,0-9.042-.643q-4.892,1.088-5.089,6.917a6.284,6.284,0,0,1-1.582,3.755c-1.813,2.007-5.221,2.932-10.13,2.866a75.709,75.709,0,0,1-14.477-1.582,59.1,59.1,0,0,1-9.042-2.569,18.1,18.1,0,0,1-7.462-5.435q-3.854-4.447,1.68-15.91t9.982-16.108A57.889,57.889,0,0,1,706.425,192.3a60.684,60.684,0,0,1,37.85,6.425q16.6,8.894,24.607,28.955t-1.78,37.453a40.841,40.841,0,0,1-24.31,19.814q-15.91,4.892-23.914,12.9,12.549-.3,25.1-.791t16.6,0q3.854.2,6.472,6.079a49.377,49.377,0,0,1,3.657,13.291,62.3,62.3,0,0,1,.4,14.379c-.428,4.645-1.552,7.736-3.311,9.339-1,.91-6.786,1.582-17.393,1.977s-22.269.592-34.982.592-24.607-.2-35.676-.592S662.153,341.088,660.176,340.232Z" transform="translate(-657.047 -191.62)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_2" data-name="2" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <path id="Path_11861" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 11861" d="M660.176,340.232q-3.36-1.878-3.112-16.8T658.1,305.25q5.579-23.213,20.556-34.835A144.034,144.034,0,0,1,714.133,250.7q8.3-3.272,7.66-6.819T717,238.595a14.694,14.694,0,0,0-9.042-.643q-4.892,1.088-5.089,6.917a6.284,6.284,0,0,1-1.582,3.755c-1.813,2.007-5.221,2.932-10.13,2.866a75.709,75.709,0,0,1-14.477-1.582,59.1,59.1,0,0,1-9.042-2.569,18.1,18.1,0,0,1-7.462-5.435q-3.854-4.447,1.68-15.91t9.982-16.108A57.889,57.889,0,0,1,706.425,192.3a60.684,60.684,0,0,1,37.85,6.425q16.6,8.894,24.607,28.955t-1.78,37.453a40.841,40.841,0,0,1-24.31,19.814q-15.91,4.892-23.914,12.9,12.549-.3,25.1-.791t16.6,0q3.854.2,6.472,6.079a49.377,49.377,0,0,1,3.657,13.291,62.3,62.3,0,0,1,.4,14.379c-.428,4.645-1.552,7.736-3.311,9.339-1,.91-6.786,1.582-17.393,1.977s-22.269.592-34.982.592-24.607-.2-35.676-.592S662.153,341.088,660.176,340.232Z" transform="translate(-657.047 -191.62)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_13" data-name="Mask Group 13" opacity="0.64" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
      <g id="Group_4567" data-name="Group 4567" transform="translate(-2.865 -8.083)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_172" data-name="Ellipse 172" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(94.386 135)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_173" data-name="Ellipse 173" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(49.386 99)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_181" data-name="Ellipse 181" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(30.386)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_182" data-name="Ellipse 182" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(76.386 25)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_174" data-name="Ellipse 174" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(19.386 123)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_175" data-name="Ellipse 175" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(80.386 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_176" data-name="Ellipse 176" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(25.386 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_177" data-name="Ellipse 177" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(16.386 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_178" data-name="Ellipse 178" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(44.386 151)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_179" data-name="Ellipse 179" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0.386 148)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_180" data-name="Ellipse 180" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(10.386 47)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_183" data-name="Ellipse 183" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(99.386 58)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

number3

```
<svg id="number3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="123.029" height="159.894" viewBox="0 0 123.029 159.894">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path3">
      <path id="Path_11867" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 11867" d="M1254.088,204.236q28.513,18.127,20.664,51.522a48.982,48.982,0,0,1-10.029,20.456,57.605,57.605,0,0,1-17.528,14.27,68.887,68.887,0,0,1-23.744,7.332,71.474,71.474,0,0,1-25.359-.738c-20.559-4.634-35.309-17.011-44.053-36.822-1.542-3.493-.292-6.78,3.7-9.837a54.927,54.927,0,0,1,14.44-7.718,77.8,77.8,0,0,1,16.534-4.225q8.081-1.1,9.878.528a6.577,6.577,0,0,1,1.847,4.014q.576,8.09,10.541,5.138t8.2-8.006q-1.983-5.57-14.791-12.376t-13.328-17.183a32.237,32.237,0,0,1,1.086-7.917q1.24-5.529,7.642-12.617-19.735.085-27.435-.593-4.993-.419-8.489-6.322a43.4,43.4,0,0,1-5.047-13.455,49.736,49.736,0,0,1-.867-14.784q.687-7.232,4.047-10.519,2.65-2.547,18.356-4.055t34.091-1.618q18.383-.11,34.249,1.182c10.578.862,16.914,2.252,18.938,4.243,4.5,4.43,4.361,13.728-.276,27.739S1258.3,196.673,1254.088,204.236Z" transform="translate(-1153.4 -138.7)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_3" data-name="3" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <path id="Path_11860" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 11860" d="M1254.088,204.236q28.513,18.127,20.664,51.522a48.982,48.982,0,0,1-10.029,20.456,57.605,57.605,0,0,1-17.528,14.27,68.887,68.887,0,0,1-23.744,7.332,71.474,71.474,0,0,1-25.359-.738c-20.559-4.634-35.309-17.011-44.053-36.822-1.542-3.493-.292-6.78,3.7-9.837a54.927,54.927,0,0,1,14.44-7.718,77.8,77.8,0,0,1,16.534-4.225q8.081-1.1,9.878.528a6.577,6.577,0,0,1,1.847,4.014q.576,8.09,10.541,5.138t8.2-8.006q-1.983-5.57-14.791-12.376t-13.328-17.183a32.237,32.237,0,0,1,1.086-7.917q1.24-5.529,7.642-12.617-19.735.085-27.435-.593-4.993-.419-8.489-6.322a43.4,43.4,0,0,1-5.047-13.455,49.736,49.736,0,0,1-.867-14.784q.687-7.232,4.047-10.519,2.65-2.547,18.356-4.055t34.091-1.618q18.383-.11,34.249,1.182c10.578.862,16.914,2.252,18.938,4.243,4.5,4.43,4.361,13.728-.276,27.739S1258.3,196.673,1254.088,204.236Z" transform="translate(-1153.4 -138.7)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_14" data-name="Mask Group 14" opacity="0.6" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
      <g id="Group_4569" data-name="Group 4569" transform="translate(122.6 171) rotate(180)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_184" data-name="Ellipse 184" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(94.362 135)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_185" data-name="Ellipse 185" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(50.362 96)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_186" data-name="Ellipse 186" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(30.362)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_187" data-name="Ellipse 187" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(76.362 25)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_188" data-name="Ellipse 188" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(30.362 134)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_189" data-name="Ellipse 189" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(47.362 53)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_190" data-name="Ellipse 190" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(25.362 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_191" data-name="Ellipse 191" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(16.362 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_192" data-name="Ellipse 192" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(49.362 161)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_193" data-name="Ellipse 193" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0.362 148)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_194" data-name="Ellipse 194" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(10.362 47)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_195" data-name="Ellipse 195" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(104.362 60)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

number4

```
<svg id="number4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="137.443" height="158.568" viewBox="0 0 137.443 158.568">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path4">
      <path id="Path_18158" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 18158" d="M1815.938,223.65q3.427,2.077,2.648,19.681c-.519,11.735-1.784,20.006-3.895,24.768q-1.432,3.229-22.743,4.466-.934,12.773-2.181,21.5t-2.7,10.8q-2.076,4.05-19.783,4.828c-11.805.521-20.131-.437-25.081-2.648-1.444-.644-2.666-4.05-3.635-10.281s-1.765-14.019-2.388-23.366q-18.693-.311-32.661-.26t-15.216-1.193q-4.05-3.427-6.178-20.667c-1.42-11.492-1.046-19.88,1.193-25.132,4.795-11.239,13.121-23.228,24.821-36.036s21.552-23.035,29.493-30.74q4.165-4.038,13.086-6.128a75.47,75.47,0,0,1,18.018-1.973,51.611,51.611,0,0,1,16.2,2.545q7.115,2.439,7.633,7.321,1.039,10.9,1.4,26.638t.155,32.764Q1813.133,221.366,1815.938,223.65Zm-63.764,8.205q.934-1.559.155-9.607t-2.024-7.217q-2.7.83-8.517,6.8t-5.816,8.569q0,1.867,7.945,1.972T1752.173,231.855Z" transform="translate(-1147.983 124.739)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_4" data-name="4" transform="translate(-533.305 -276)">
    <path id="Path_72" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 72" d="M1815.938,223.65q3.427,2.077,2.648,19.681c-.519,11.735-1.784,20.006-3.895,24.768q-1.432,3.229-22.743,4.466-.934,12.773-2.181,21.5t-2.7,10.8q-2.076,4.05-19.783,4.828c-11.805.521-20.131-.437-25.081-2.648-1.444-.644-2.666-4.05-3.635-10.281s-1.765-14.019-2.388-23.366q-18.693-.311-32.661-.26t-15.216-1.193q-4.05-3.427-6.178-20.667c-1.42-11.492-1.046-19.88,1.193-25.132,4.795-11.239,13.121-23.228,24.821-36.036s21.552-23.035,29.493-30.74q4.165-4.038,13.086-6.128a75.47,75.47,0,0,1,18.018-1.973,51.611,51.611,0,0,1,16.2,2.545q7.115,2.439,7.633,7.321,1.039,10.9,1.4,26.638t.155,32.764Q1813.133,221.366,1815.938,223.65Zm-63.764,8.205q.934-1.559.155-9.607t-2.024-7.217q-2.7.83-8.517,6.8t-5.816,8.569q0,1.867,7.945,1.972T1752.173,231.855Z" transform="translate(-1147.983 124.739)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_16" data-name="Mask Group 16" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
      <g id="Group_8842" data-name="Group 8842" transform="matrix(-0.966, 0.259, -0.259, -0.966, 686.854, 428.569)" opacity="0.51" style="isolation: isolate">
        <circle id="Ellipse_196" data-name="Ellipse 196" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(69.455 134.066)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_197" data-name="Ellipse 197" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(51.121 99)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_198" data-name="Ellipse 198" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(32.121)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_208" data-name="Ellipse 208" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(115.084 57.429)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_199" data-name="Ellipse 199" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(71.291 27.311)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_200" data-name="Ellipse 200" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(32.121 134)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_201" data-name="Ellipse 201" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(49.121 53)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_202" data-name="Ellipse 202" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(18.687 70.705)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_209" data-name="Ellipse 209" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(84.508 80.059)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_203" data-name="Ellipse 203" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(18.121 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_211" data-name="Ellipse 211" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(-10.579 76.745)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_205" data-name="Ellipse 205" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0 144.326)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_206" data-name="Ellipse 206" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(14.053 47.517)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_210" data-name="Ellipse 210" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(81.927 64.669)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_207" data-name="Ellipse 207" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(98.578 119.061)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: shouldn't number3 and number4 point to clip-path3 and clip-path4 respectively. They don't and I assume that's a problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson You mean this part in the url ? clip-path="url(#clip-path)"

Comment: Yes, that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observation by @RobertLongson above is absolutely correct.

You need each **`clip-path` url reference** to match up with the `id` of the `<clipPath>` element above it.

At present, that means using:

- `clip-path="url(#clip-path)"`
- `clip-path="url(#clip-path3)"`
- `clip-path="url(#clip-path4)"`

in your respective `<svg>` elements.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

#number2 {
  color: rgb(255, 48, 48);
}

#number3 {
  color: rgb(92, 210, 247);
}

#number4 {
  color: rgb(255, 209, 95);
}
```

```html
<svg id="number2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="115.436" height="151.083" viewBox="0 0 115.436 151.083">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <path id="Path_11866" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 11866" d="M660.176,340.232q-3.36-1.878-3.112-16.8T658.1,305.25q5.579-23.213,20.556-34.835A144.034,144.034,0,0,1,714.133,250.7q8.3-3.272,7.66-6.819T717,238.595a14.694,14.694,0,0,0-9.042-.643q-4.892,1.088-5.089,6.917a6.284,6.284,0,0,1-1.582,3.755c-1.813,2.007-5.221,2.932-10.13,2.866a75.709,75.709,0,0,1-14.477-1.582,59.1,59.1,0,0,1-9.042-2.569,18.1,18.1,0,0,1-7.462-5.435q-3.854-4.447,1.68-15.91t9.982-16.108A57.889,57.889,0,0,1,706.425,192.3a60.684,60.684,0,0,1,37.85,6.425q16.6,8.894,24.607,28.955t-1.78,37.453a40.841,40.841,0,0,1-24.31,19.814q-15.91,4.892-23.914,12.9,12.549-.3,25.1-.791t16.6,0q3.854.2,6.472,6.079a49.377,49.377,0,0,1,3.657,13.291,62.3,62.3,0,0,1,.4,14.379c-.428,4.645-1.552,7.736-3.311,9.339-1,.91-6.786,1.582-17.393,1.977s-22.269.592-34.982.592-24.607-.2-35.676-.592S662.153,341.088,660.176,340.232Z" transform="translate(-657.047 -191.62)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_2" data-name="2" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <path id="Path_11861" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 11861" d="M660.176,340.232q-3.36-1.878-3.112-16.8T658.1,305.25q5.579-23.213,20.556-34.835A144.034,144.034,0,0,1,714.133,250.7q8.3-3.272,7.66-6.819T717,238.595a14.694,14.694,0,0,0-9.042-.643q-4.892,1.088-5.089,6.917a6.284,6.284,0,0,1-1.582,3.755c-1.813,2.007-5.221,2.932-10.13,2.866a75.709,75.709,0,0,1-14.477-1.582,59.1,59.1,0,0,1-9.042-2.569,18.1,18.1,0,0,1-7.462-5.435q-3.854-4.447,1.68-15.91t9.982-16.108A57.889,57.889,0,0,1,706.425,192.3a60.684,60.684,0,0,1,37.85,6.425q16.6,8.894,24.607,28.955t-1.78,37.453a40.841,40.841,0,0,1-24.31,19.814q-15.91,4.892-23.914,12.9,12.549-.3,25.1-.791t16.6,0q3.854.2,6.472,6.079a49.377,49.377,0,0,1,3.657,13.291,62.3,62.3,0,0,1,.4,14.379c-.428,4.645-1.552,7.736-3.311,9.339-1,.91-6.786,1.582-17.393,1.977s-22.269.592-34.982.592-24.607-.2-35.676-.592S662.153,341.088,660.176,340.232Z" transform="translate(-657.047 -191.62)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_13" data-name="Mask Group 13" opacity="0.64" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
      <g id="Group_4567" data-name="Group 4567" transform="translate(-2.865 -8.083)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_172" data-name="Ellipse 172" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(94.386 135)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_173" data-name="Ellipse 173" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(49.386 99)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_181" data-name="Ellipse 181" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(30.386)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_182" data-name="Ellipse 182" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(76.386 25)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_174" data-name="Ellipse 174" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(19.386 123)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_175" data-name="Ellipse 175" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(80.386 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_176" data-name="Ellipse 176" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(25.386 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_177" data-name="Ellipse 177" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(16.386 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_178" data-name="Ellipse 178" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(44.386 151)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_179" data-name="Ellipse 179" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0.386 148)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_180" data-name="Ellipse 180" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(10.386 47)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_183" data-name="Ellipse 183" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(99.386 58)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg id="number3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="123.029" height="159.894" viewBox="0 0 123.029 159.894">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path3">
      <path id="Path_11867" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 11867" d="M1254.088,204.236q28.513,18.127,20.664,51.522a48.982,48.982,0,0,1-10.029,20.456,57.605,57.605,0,0,1-17.528,14.27,68.887,68.887,0,0,1-23.744,7.332,71.474,71.474,0,0,1-25.359-.738c-20.559-4.634-35.309-17.011-44.053-36.822-1.542-3.493-.292-6.78,3.7-9.837a54.927,54.927,0,0,1,14.44-7.718,77.8,77.8,0,0,1,16.534-4.225q8.081-1.1,9.878.528a6.577,6.577,0,0,1,1.847,4.014q.576,8.09,10.541,5.138t8.2-8.006q-1.983-5.57-14.791-12.376t-13.328-17.183a32.237,32.237,0,0,1,1.086-7.917q1.24-5.529,7.642-12.617-19.735.085-27.435-.593-4.993-.419-8.489-6.322a43.4,43.4,0,0,1-5.047-13.455,49.736,49.736,0,0,1-.867-14.784q.687-7.232,4.047-10.519,2.65-2.547,18.356-4.055t34.091-1.618q18.383-.11,34.249,1.182c10.578.862,16.914,2.252,18.938,4.243,4.5,4.43,4.361,13.728-.276,27.739S1258.3,196.673,1254.088,204.236Z" transform="translate(-1153.4 -138.7)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_3" data-name="3" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <path id="Path_11860" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 11860" d="M1254.088,204.236q28.513,18.127,20.664,51.522a48.982,48.982,0,0,1-10.029,20.456,57.605,57.605,0,0,1-17.528,14.27,68.887,68.887,0,0,1-23.744,7.332,71.474,71.474,0,0,1-25.359-.738c-20.559-4.634-35.309-17.011-44.053-36.822-1.542-3.493-.292-6.78,3.7-9.837a54.927,54.927,0,0,1,14.44-7.718,77.8,77.8,0,0,1,16.534-4.225q8.081-1.1,9.878.528a6.577,6.577,0,0,1,1.847,4.014q.576,8.09,10.541,5.138t8.2-8.006q-1.983-5.57-14.791-12.376t-13.328-17.183a32.237,32.237,0,0,1,1.086-7.917q1.24-5.529,7.642-12.617-19.735.085-27.435-.593-4.993-.419-8.489-6.322a43.4,43.4,0,0,1-5.047-13.455,49.736,49.736,0,0,1-.867-14.784q.687-7.232,4.047-10.519,2.65-2.547,18.356-4.055t34.091-1.618q18.383-.11,34.249,1.182c10.578.862,16.914,2.252,18.938,4.243,4.5,4.43,4.361,13.728-.276,27.739S1258.3,196.673,1254.088,204.236Z" transform="translate(-1153.4 -138.7)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_14" data-name="Mask Group 14" opacity="0.6" clip-path="url(#clip-path3)">
      <g id="Group_4569" data-name="Group 4569" transform="translate(122.6 171) rotate(180)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_184" data-name="Ellipse 184" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(94.362 135)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_185" data-name="Ellipse 185" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(50.362 96)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_186" data-name="Ellipse 186" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(30.362)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_187" data-name="Ellipse 187" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(76.362 25)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_188" data-name="Ellipse 188" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(30.362 134)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_189" data-name="Ellipse 189" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(47.362 53)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_190" data-name="Ellipse 190" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(25.362 74)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_191" data-name="Ellipse 191" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(16.362 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_192" data-name="Ellipse 192" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(49.362 161)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_193" data-name="Ellipse 193" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0.362 148)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_194" data-name="Ellipse 194" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(10.362 47)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_195" data-name="Ellipse 195" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(104.362 60)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg id="number4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="137.443" height="158.568" viewBox="0 0 137.443 158.568">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path4">
      <path id="Path_18158" fill="#fff" data-name="Path 18158" d="M1815.938,223.65q3.427,2.077,2.648,19.681c-.519,11.735-1.784,20.006-3.895,24.768q-1.432,3.229-22.743,4.466-.934,12.773-2.181,21.5t-2.7,10.8q-2.076,4.05-19.783,4.828c-11.805.521-20.131-.437-25.081-2.648-1.444-.644-2.666-4.05-3.635-10.281s-1.765-14.019-2.388-23.366q-18.693-.311-32.661-.26t-15.216-1.193q-4.05-3.427-6.178-20.667c-1.42-11.492-1.046-19.88,1.193-25.132,4.795-11.239,13.121-23.228,24.821-36.036s21.552-23.035,29.493-30.74q4.165-4.038,13.086-6.128a75.47,75.47,0,0,1,18.018-1.973,51.611,51.611,0,0,1,16.2,2.545q7.115,2.439,7.633,7.321,1.039,10.9,1.4,26.638t.155,32.764Q1813.133,221.366,1815.938,223.65Zm-63.764,8.205q.934-1.559.155-9.607t-2.024-7.217q-2.7.83-8.517,6.8t-5.816,8.569q0,1.867,7.945,1.972T1752.173,231.855Z" transform="translate(-1147.983 124.739)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="_4" data-name="4" transform="translate(-533.305 -276)">
    <path id="Path_72" fill="currentcolor" data-name="Path 72" d="M1815.938,223.65q3.427,2.077,2.648,19.681c-.519,11.735-1.784,20.006-3.895,24.768q-1.432,3.229-22.743,4.466-.934,12.773-2.181,21.5t-2.7,10.8q-2.076,4.05-19.783,4.828c-11.805.521-20.131-.437-25.081-2.648-1.444-.644-2.666-4.05-3.635-10.281s-1.765-14.019-2.388-23.366q-18.693-.311-32.661-.26t-15.216-1.193q-4.05-3.427-6.178-20.667c-1.42-11.492-1.046-19.88,1.193-25.132,4.795-11.239,13.121-23.228,24.821-36.036s21.552-23.035,29.493-30.74q4.165-4.038,13.086-6.128a75.47,75.47,0,0,1,18.018-1.973,51.611,51.611,0,0,1,16.2,2.545q7.115,2.439,7.633,7.321,1.039,10.9,1.4,26.638t.155,32.764Q1813.133,221.366,1815.938,223.65Zm-63.764,8.205q.934-1.559.155-9.607t-2.024-7.217q-2.7.83-8.517,6.8t-5.816,8.569q0,1.867,7.945,1.972T1752.173,231.855Z" transform="translate(-1147.983 124.739)"/>
    <g id="Mask_Group_16" data-name="Mask Group 16" clip-path="url(#clip-path4)">
      <g id="Group_8842" data-name="Group 8842" transform="matrix(-0.966, 0.259, -0.259, -0.966, 686.854, 428.569)" opacity="0.51" style="isolation: isolate">
        <circle id="Ellipse_196" data-name="Ellipse 196" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(69.455 134.066)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_197" data-name="Ellipse 197" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(51.121 99)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_198" data-name="Ellipse 198" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(32.121)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_208" data-name="Ellipse 208" cx="19.5" cy="19.5" r="19.5" transform="translate(115.084 57.429)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_199" data-name="Ellipse 199" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="13.5" transform="translate(71.291 27.311)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_200" data-name="Ellipse 200" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(32.121 134)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_201" data-name="Ellipse 201" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(49.121 53)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_202" data-name="Ellipse 202" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(18.687 70.705)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_209" data-name="Ellipse 209" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(84.508 80.059)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_203" data-name="Ellipse 203" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(18.121 101)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_211" data-name="Ellipse 211" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(-10.579 76.745)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_205" data-name="Ellipse 205" cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" transform="translate(0 144.326)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_206" data-name="Ellipse 206" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(14.053 47.517)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_210" data-name="Ellipse 210" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(81.927 64.669)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_207" data-name="Ellipse 207" cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4.5" transform="translate(98.578 119.061)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```